# Finding all permutations which follow reflection symmetry

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, permutation-cycles

I am unsure how to write down these questions formally, so here is some python code and the problem in words.

I am looking to find all permutations which subscribe to reflective symmetry. For example, given the permutation group $G$ over e.g. {1,2,3,4,5} then I am looking for e.g. {1,2,3,2,1} or {2,2,2,2,2} - i.e. those permutations which are reflective about the center of the permutation.

In code:

```
n = 6 # length of set
r = 4 # selection
a = [range(n)]*r
all_layouts = list(product(*a))
```

To find all symmetric permutations:

```
symmetric_layout = []
r2 = r//2
for t in all_motor_layouts:
    is_symmetric = True
    for i in range(r2):
        if t[i] != t[r - i - 1]:
            is_symmetric = False
            break
    if is_symmetric:
        symmetric_layout.append(t)
```

Examples of `all_layouts`:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 0, 0, 1),
 (0, 0, 0, 2),
 (0, 0, 0, 3),
 (0, 0, 0, 4),
 (0, 0, 0, 5),
 (0, 0, 1, 0),
 (0, 0, 1, 1),
 (0, 0, 1, 2),
 (0, 0, 1, 3),...]
```

Example of `symmetric_layout`:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 1, 0),
 (0, 2, 2, 0),
 (0, 3, 3, 0),
 (0, 4, 4, 0),
 (0, 5, 5, 0),
 (1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1),
 (1, 2, 2, 1),...]
```

Questions:

1. How is this problem more formally described? (palindrome permutations?) I.e. to find a sub-group of permutations which subscribe to some particular symmetry?
2. How can we find this group without, as above, enumerating all of them and seeing if they subscribe to our desired symmetry?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by a permutation like $\{2,2,2,2,2\}$?  Usually a permutation means a bijection from a set to itself...this looks more like a constant function.

Comment: I may have phrased it incorrectly (I do not have the vocabulary for this). In the above example, one will find e.g. `(2,2,2,2)` in the space of symmetric combinations of the symbols. In the five-letter string, I meant the same thing. But as said, I may have phrased this poorly.

Comment: I don't understand.  I think (but am not at all sure) that what you mean is "Let $S$ be the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  How many functions are there from $S\to S$ such that $f(1)=f(5)$ and $f(2)=f(4)$? (with a similar question for $n$ instead of $5$)."  If so the answer is $5^3$, since you can specify $f(1), f(2), f(3)$ however you like.  But my guess as to your question might be way off.

Comment: Yes. That. That is precisely what I mean. Thank you. And then onto the second question, how can we find this subgroup given $S$? Is there a better way than enumeration?

Comment: There is no group here, and these are not permutations.  The constant function $f(i)=2\,\forall i$ is not invertible.

Comment: I wish I knew what that meant... okay thanks. More googling it would seem.

Comment: But the count is easy.  If $n=2k$ then there are $n^k$ such functions and if $n=2k+1$ there are $n^{k+1}$.  Same argument as in the case $n=5$.  Just assign values to the first half of the arguments.

Comment: One more naive question perhaps: why is it not possible to find all sequences which conform to the constant function $f$, given $S$?

Comment: I don't understand. My count includes the constants. There are $n$ of them.